# How to read JSON response from Google web services in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find the distance between two locations. For that I used Google web services. I got a JSON response from that web service, but I am unable to get the distance from that JSON response in a javascript function.

See my code below:

```
function myjourneysubdetails(){
  var fp = jQuery('#fp').val();
  var tp = jQuery('#tp').val();
  var city = jQuery('#city').val();
  alert(fp);
  $.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Silk board&destinations=marathahalli&language=en-US&sensor=false',
    async: false,
    success : function(data) {
      alert("Success");
      var locObject = eval('(' + JSON.stringify(data) + ')');
      alert("locObject: "+locObject);
      alert("Destination: "+locObject.destination_addresses);
      var origins = data.origin_addresses;
      var destinations = data.destination_addresses;
      alert('destinations'+destinations);
      for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
        var results = data.rows[i].elements;
        for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
          var element = results[j];
          var distance = element.distance.text;
          var duration = element.duration.text;
          var from = origins[i];
          var to = destinations[j];
          alert('distance'+distance);
        }
      }
    },
    error : function(xhr, type) {
      alert('Internal Error Occoured! '+xhr+' : '+type); 
    }
  });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hm, it looks like that URL doesn't allow cross-domain requests, and also it doesn't support JSONP.  Not sure what you can do to fix that ...

Comment: i just checked the response is coming prperly as json response ant it has your distance calculated , would you please be specific what prob are you facing in retrieving the distance value , its right there in your json response , kindly print the url in chrome browser hit enter , see where your value is and retrieve it

Comment: well i am just calculating it , let you know it asap

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is called the "[same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)" of web browsers.

Basically, as one of numerous security measures implemented by web browsers (and one of the earliest to be proposed and implemented) you are not allowed to make ajax requests to a domain which is different from the url of the web page. So, the only way for your code to work as is is if you can manage to convince google to host your page on the `maps.googleapis.com` domain.

Obviously that won't work. There are several work-arounds to this. The current most popular method is JSONP. Unfortunately google maps does not support JSONP. There are several other methods such as using flash or java applets to forward the request for you. But the simplest, most compatible method is the original solution to this problem: proxy the request on your server.

The reason proxying works is because programming languages and web servers, unlike web browsers, don't care where you connect to on the internet. There are several ways you can do this. You can either write a web app to do the proxying (an example is this simple proxy in PHP: https://github.com/cowboy/php-simple-proxy/) or configure your web server to proxy your request (for example using apache mod_proxy or mod_rewrite) or you can use a dedicated proxy server installed on your server.

So for example, in your code you should really be doing this:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : 'http://myserver.com/proxy/distancematrix/json?origins=Silk board&destinations=marathahalli&language=en-US&sensor=false',
```

And then configure your server to forward that request with something like this:

```
# Example of Apache mod_rewrite proxying:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/proxy/(.*) http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/$1 [P]
```

### A word of warning:

However you do it, remember that this is the internet. Do not write an open proxy. If you do you run the risk of hackers using your proxy to forward spam, DOS attacks etc. and you'll get the blame because it would appear to come from your server. The best way to prevent this is to hardcode the proxy url to google maps so that people can't use your server to connect to anywhere else. Just forward the query parameters, not the whole url.